# Will and would modal verbs

Tags: time, sequence-of-tenses, will-would

Which of the following sentences is correct? If both are correct, what is
the difference in meaning between these two sentences?

1. A majority of voters approved changes to Russia’s Constitution that **would** allow president Vladimir Putin to hold power until 2036.
2. A majority of voters approved changes to Russia’s Constitution that **will** allow president Vladimir Putin to hold power until 2036.

I know that because the sentence is in the past tense, we should use *would*.

But considering that the Constitution is still allowing this, and will
allow it for some time in the future, can’t we use *will*?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Changes would not be reflected" vs. "Changes will not be reflected"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4418/changes-would-not-be-reflected-vs-changes-will-not-be-reflected)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is this noun phrase

- *changes to Russia's constitution*

and its attendant relative clause

- *that ___ allow president Putin to hold power until 2036*.

The question is, what fits into the blank?

And the answer is, just about anything, certainly any modal auxiliary verb, starting with nothing at all:

- *that allow president Putin to hold power until 2036*.
- *that will allow president Putin to hold power until 2036*.
- *that would allow president Putin to hold power until 2036*.
- *that could allow president Putin to hold power until 2036*.
- *that might allow president Putin to hold power until 2036*.
- *that may allow president Putin to hold power until 2036*.
- *that should allow president Putin to hold power until 2036*.

... and so on.

TL;DR - *will* is not "future tense", and *would* is not "conditional mood".
Both are [modal auxiliary verbs](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/465282/15299).

Answer (score 0):

Both are correct. "Would" = it allows Putin to do it but he won't definitely do it. "Will allow" = same as would except it sounds more certain that Putin will do it.

Answer (score -3):

The first one is correct.

We use **would** as a past form of 'will'.

(...**approved**...**would**...)

...*approve*...*will*...

We use **will** for a prediction.

The fair **will** last for fifteen days.

We use **would** for a past prediction or a prediction about a possible situation.

'How about going to the cinema next Sunday.' 'That **would** be nice.' (possible)

She will talk to him for hours. (present habit)

She would talk to him for hours. (past habit)

[He *will* buy a shirt.

He *said* that he *would* buy a shirt.]

Comment: In "A majority of voters approved changes to Russia’s Constitution that will allow president Vladimir Putin to hold power until 2036" it isn't a past prediction; it could be a prediction in the present based on a past action.